# Passing data from an HTML form to PHP file

Tags: php, html, forms

Any help understanding why the below does not work would be a big help.  I don't understand why $var1 does not get the contents of bnum in the PHP file.

Thank
Marc

### HTML form in file#1

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="delete.php" method="post">
Please input building number to delete: <input type="text" name="bnum"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

### Delete.php file

```
<?php
echo $_POST["bnum"];
echo "<br>"; 

$var1 = $_post["bnum"];
echo "var1 = ";
echo $var1;
echo "<br>";

var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

### Output

```
test
var1 = 
array(1) { ["bnum"]=> string(4) "test" }
```

Comment: $_post != $_POST

Comment: Not sure how to show a palm to forehead slap here.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$_post is not the same like $_POST...

```
$var1 = $_POST["bnum"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine!

You entered "test" into the text field.
You echoed the posted text and you got line 1 of the output "test".
You echoed "Var =" string and you got "var =".
You requested string information and line 3 told you that it is 4 characters and it is "test".

This script would need to connect to a database to actually do something meaningful. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, $_post as you already know is not like Global variable $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

big letters for $_post.. like this  $_POST['bnum']

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` like `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`,`$_COOKIE` and `$_SESSION` (*amongst others*), are known as [**"Superglobals"**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and **must** be in uppercase letters, *no exception.*

```
<?php
echo $_POST["bnum"];
echo "<br>"; 

$var1 = $_post["bnum"]; // INVALID $_post must be in uppercase
echo "var1 = ";
echo $var1;
echo "<br>";

var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

**Valid:**

```
<?php
echo $_POST["bnum"];
echo "<br>"; 

$var1 = $_POST["bnum"]; // VALID
echo "var1 = ";
echo $var1;
echo "<br>";

var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

- For the complete list of [**Superglobals**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and documentation, visit the PHP.net Website.
- **http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php**